# Dynamic link in left navigation menu

Tags: master-page, navigation, hyperlink, onedrive-for-business, mysite

We are using SharePoint 2013 on-premise. We have deployed a custom master page where we have removed the links for "One drive", "Sites" etc on the top right corner.

We want to have a dynamic link in the left navigation menu in the my site host, that is shown to all users. We want to point the link to a users "one drive".

I am not quite sure how to achieve this as the left navigation menu is static, and the link is different for all users as it point to the users my site. Any good ideas on how I somehow can get a dynamic link?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Links in the QuickLaunch are static, but...

You can make a link to a static Redirect Page (or Custom APSX Page), where you extract the link to OneDrive and redirect to it with `window.location=`

They will see a blank page.. or make a nice redirect text (just in case somewhting goes wrong in your script)

Comment: Thanks for the input man. I think this will do the trick for me. I can develop some logic in application page which I can point the link in the left navigation menu to.